# System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode and System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode methods differences

Tags: c#, url

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8) of the **System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(String)** method character codes should be encoded with low-case letters, at least in the example it's stated so: "*For example, when embedded in a block of text to be transmitted in a URL, the characters < and > are encoded as %3c and %3e.*"
But I get all of them in upper case. For example this code:

```
string url = "https://host<test>";
Console.WriteLine("system.net: {0}", System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Gives me the following:

> system.net: https%3A%2F%2Fhost%3Ctest%3E

On the other side **System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode** gives me all in low case:

```
string url = "https://host<test>";
Console.WriteLine("system.web: {0}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Output:

> system.web: https%3a%2f%2fhost%3ctest%3e

Is it expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it expected?

Looks like it is expected. Going through the source code [`WebUtility`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs) I see that public `UrlEncode` calls one of the private one

```
    public static string UrlEncode(string value)
    {
      // code stripped
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UrlEncode(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, false /* alwaysCreateNewReturnValue */));
    }

    //private one makes a call to IntToHex
    private static byte[] UrlEncode(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count)
    {
      expandedBytes[pos++] = (byte)IntToHex((b >> 4) & 0xf);

    // IntToHex casting to uppercase character, reason being every 
    // encoded character is returning as uppercase.
    private static char IntToHex(int n)
    {
       //code stripped
        else
            return (char)(n - 10 + (int)'A');  //here
    }
```